# SAS Proc Arima forecast graph with actuals

Tags: sas

Does proc Arima allow for the forecast plot to show actuals and forecast. I haven't been able to find any option. So far I have been merging forecast data to the actual data and plotting it. It is just an additional step that I want to avoid.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  You want the FORECAST(FORECAST) plot (confusing, I agree).

Try this:

```
data seriesg;
set sashelp.air;
xlog = log(air);
run;

proc arima data=seriesg plots(only)=(forecast(FORECAST));
   identify var=xlog(1,12);
   estimate q=(1)(12) noint method=ml;
   forecast id=date interval=month printall out=b;
run;
quit;
```